# Redirect / show view after generated file is dowloaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a controller action that downloads a dynamically generated file:

```
    public ActionResult DownloadFile()
    {
        var obj = new MyClass { MyString = "Hello", MyBool = true };
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        ser.Serialize(stream, obj);
        stream.Position = 0;

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xml");
        Response.ContentType = "application/xml";

        // Write all my data
        stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.End();

        return Content("Downloaded");
    }
```

Just for reference:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string MyString { get; set; }
        public int MyInt { get; set; }
    }
```

This is working, and the file (myfile.xml) is downloaded.
However, the message "Downloaded" is not sent to the browser.

Similarly, if I replace `return Content("Downloaded");`
for `return Redirect("www.something.com");`
then the browser is redirected before the file downloads.

As a bit of a pre-amble, the user journey is:

- User fills out form on previous view
- Form is submitted
- XML is generated and downloaded
- User is redirected / "Downloaded" view is shown *(so hitting F5 won't re-post the form)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each HTTP request can only have one response - you're trying to sneak in two (the file, and a page).

Normally when you send a "Content-Disposition: attachment" HTTP header the browser will stay on the current page and pop a file save dialog (or automatically save the file in your downloads).

You're going to have to change your strategy if you want to prevent re-submission of the form. I'd suggest a bit of javascript to disable the form's submit button and show the "Completed" message in a div overlay?

Answer (score 11):

As Ross has said, you can only return one response to a HTTP request.
What i do in that case is:

1. Send the request to the server
2. The server generates the file and stores it in some server side data structure (Cache, Usersession, TempData)
3. The server returns a `RedirectToAction()` (POST, REDIRECT, GET pattern)
4. The redirected action returns a View with some javascript which
5. Triggers the download of the pregenerated file by setting `window.location.href` property to an special download action which sends the file back to the browser

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I redirected after the file is downloaded.
The main logic is to wait the redirect until the file is downloaded.
To do that, a server side response is calculated and redirect is delayed using server side response time + some offset.

Server Side Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetTemplate()
    {
        return Json(new {Url = Url.Action("ReturnTemplate") });
    }

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ReturnTemplate()
    {
        FileResult fileResult = // your file path ;
        return fileResult;
    }
```

Client Side Code:

```
<div id="btnGen" align="right"><button class="main-button"     id="generateTemplate" type="Submit"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#generateTemplate").click(function () {
    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime(), endTime;

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetTemplate", "Controller")',
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(),
            success: function (result) {
                endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                var serverResponseTime = endTime - startTime + 500;
                setInterval(function () { Back() }, serverResponseTime);
                window.location = result.Url;
            }
        });
});

function Back() {
    window.location = '@Url.Action("Index","Controller")';
}
```