# how to redirect to another page in MVC after Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect

In my project the user can search the details of the school students and export the same to excel. I am using `OpenOfficeXMl` for achieving this.
The excel is downloading with the data once the search button is clicked.

Is it possible  to redirect to an another page after the excel download is completed.

I am assigning the data to a datatable, then it is extracting to the excel as below.

```
using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("PData");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(p_data, true);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=School-" + DateTime.Now + "-file" + ".xlsx");
    Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

Is it possible to do a `return View()` or `Redirect` after `Response.End()`?

**Edit**

After the excel is downloaded I need to navigate to another page to show the same data which is exported in excel. like `return View(Data)`
where `Data` is a `IpagedList` Object

Comment: It's been forever since I've written web applications, but AFAIK you can't use any of the `Response` object methods after `Response.End()`. why not do a Response.Redirect() after the `using` and just remove the `Response.End()` from there?

Comment: I think this could help you...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065697/redirect-show-view-after-generated-file-is-dowloaded

Comment: @ZoharPeled thanks for the reply..In `Response.Redirect()` its need to specify a url..here my requirement is i need to show a page with the same details exported to excel..such as return `View(data)` where `data` is ipagedList item

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an excel file to the response and at the same time redirect.

In this case, an approach could be to simply return a View, and pass a view model that contains your IpagedList as well as the link to your pdf. No need for a redirect; unless your previous action was a POST.

In the resulting page you then can show the IpagedList information and also a link they can click download the excel file, or even download this automatically from jquery, for example by opening a new window with the URL pointing to your pdf.