# How to redirect a page after file download?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to redirect a page after download the file. But the file only download not redirect the page

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.Save("Sample.docx", FormatType.Docx, HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response, HttpContentDisposition.Attachment);
return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
```

Comment: Possible to duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065697/redirect-show-view-after-generated-file-is-dowloaded

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to accomplish that by returning a [multipart/mixed](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) response where the first part is the file to be downloaded and the second part is a [META http-equiv="refresh"](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H76.html) tag with the url to redirect to.

This solution works fine on Mozilla Firefox (tested on version 42.0), not sure about other browsers.

Here is an unpolished example of how to do it on Ruby on Rails:

```ruby
_multipart_response_boundary = '---------------------------8142823132435752456881845357'

_multipart_body = '_multipart_response_boundary' + "\r\n"

_multipart_body << 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo_bar.pdf"' + "\r\n"
_multipart_body << 'Content-Type: application/pdf' + "\r\n"
_multipart_body << "\r\n" + 'file contents' + "\r\n"

_multipart_body << '_multipart_response_boundary' + "\r\n"

_multipart_body << "\r\n" + '<html><head><META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://www.example.com"></head><body></body></html>' + "\r\n"

_multipart_body << "\r\n" + '_multipart_response_boundary' + "--\r\n"

render(:content_type => ('multipart/mixed; boundary=' + _multipart_response_boundary), :text => _multipart_body)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would look into making your download request in ajax and having your direction action be in the success block. A controller can't have two responses.

Comment: Explain to me how anything you said is relevant to my answer. I provided him an answer and offered no critique at all.