# How to pass model plus additional parameter from view to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Using ASP.NET MVC, in my view, I list some files and show them as a button. By clicking each button the corresponding file should be downloaded.

To show the list of files, I pass a model to view and when a user clicks on each of those buttons, I have to send the filename plus the original model back to the controller.

I found answers for a similar question but in my case, I don't have only one button. I have one button for each filename that I render on view.

This is the code for my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DownloadFile", "SharedFolder", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">Files</div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="max-height:300px; height:300px; overflow-y:scroll">
                @foreach (var file in Model.Files)
                {
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-sm" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "SharedFolder", new { fileToDownload = file, data = Model })'">
                        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-file" style="color:dodgerblue">
                            <span style="color:black;">@file</span>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                    <br />
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And my controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileToDownload, FolderExplorerViewModel data)
    {
        // download the file and return Index view
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

When I click on a file to download it, I get below error:

> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Requested URL: /SharedFolder/DownloadFile

**Update:**

This is my ViewModel

```
public class FolderExplorerViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
    public List<string> Files { get; set; }
    public string SelectedPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your `FolderExplorerViewModel ` structure. Why do you need this one?

Comment: I added it but not sure if it helps for getting answer.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't store `data = Model` like this causes the performance and security problem.

You just store one `fileToDownload` value from View. After that, in Controller, You should get file by `fileToDownload` param.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileToDownload)
{
    // download the file by `fileToDownload` param here

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: @FLICKER Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help

Comment: How can I get the model back in controller?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting that error is because, its trying to do form post and there are no form html elements representing fileToDownload and data.

Actually, instead of using form POST you can use anchor tags invoking controller GET action (since its just download, no need to use POST here). As @Phong mentioned, using fileToDownload you probably can retrieve other information which is needed for redirection to Index.

```
@foreach (var file in Model.Files)
{
    <a href='@Url.Action("DownloadFile", "SharedFolder", new { fileToDownload = file})' title="Click here to download the file">@file</a>
}
```

and then your controller action will be:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileToDownload)
{
    // do the stuff
    // download would return FileResult on success, not sure what you meant by RedirectToAction("Index")
    // download the file and return Index view
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If you still wanted to send Model, then you can do that via javascript button click event with ajax.

Comment: Thanks for answer let me find how I can send model back to controller using ajax. I also think to download a file, I need POST. not sure if I can download using ajax

Comment: if you wanted to download file why are you having RedirectToAction? I think, you still can not do two things event with Form Post - Download and Redirect. Trying to understand your requirement - why do you need Model - I mean purpose?

Comment: I redirect after downloading file. I think I can do that, because in ASP WebForms, I have done download and redirect. so I thought I can do that here too.

Comment: Per my knowledge, I dont think you can do both in MVC. After downloading the file, you will need to return the file contents correct? After you return the file contents, you are out of this action scope. how can you still redirect? By the way, why do you need model?

Comment: I'll try it and will let you know.

Comment: Redirect after download is not working. However there is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065697/redirect-show-view-after-generated-file-is-dowloaded for my case it is not really necessary to redirect though.

Comment: If you don't redirection, why do you need Model now? Also, if its just file download, your requirement is way simple. As shown above in my answer, without form tag, just have for loop with some anchor tags.

Comment: I guess I don't need to redirect, but if I want to do something else, still my question is valid and I'm interested to know the answer.